# Change AngularJS urls with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, ngroute

Is there any way to change AngularJS urls  with ng-model?

```js
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.gettext = function (){
          
    };
});
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="scotchApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="eventChange.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainController">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1">Search</div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" ng-change="gettext()"></div>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to change the URL into something like this http://localhost/angulRoute/search=myVal when user type 'myVal' in the search box (actually inside gettext() function with search value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.query = $location.search().q;

$scope.$watch('query', function(newValue) {
    $location.search('q', newValue);
});
```

You'd need to inject $location into your controller, and make sure in your route config includes:

```
reloadOnSearch: true
```

That would result in a URL like http://localhost/myRoute?q=myVal

Note: I would also add ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}" to your input, to prevent updating the URL on every key press.

**EXAMPLE**

Here is a working example of how to do this: http://plnkr.co/edit/tphqPeJ0dO74Ux7WpXlU?p=preview

Note that, because of the way plnkr.co works, you won't see the URL changes in the address bar on that site. If you download the code and run it locally, the URL would be updated in the address bar.

Comment: Hi @Shaun Scovil, <code> var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('search', function(newValue) {
        $routeParams.search = newValue;
    });
}).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    reloadOnSearch: true;
});
</code> I added like this but seems not working. forgive me if I'm wrong but I'm new to AngularJs

Comment: You need to inject $routeParams into your controller. Do that by simply adding it as an argument to your controller function, like this: scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $routeParams) { ... });

Comment: Also, you are not configuring your route correctly. Use $routeProvider.when('/myRoute', { templateUrl: '/path/to/template.html', controller: 'mainController', reloadOnSearch: true }); -- docs are here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: After experimenting with this, I found that updating `$routeParams` does not update the URL in the address bar. However, you can use the `$location.search()` method to get/set the query parameters. Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/tphqPeJ0dO74Ux7WpXlU?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shaun Scovil

Comment: No problem. I think you could also use $route.updateParams(), which is essentially the same as $location.search() when setting the query params.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found a javascript solution for that.

```
 $scope.gettext = function (search){
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/angulRoute/search="+search);
};
```

with `<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" ng-change="gettext(search)" >` worked for me. However anyone have an AngulerJs solution they are welcome :D